# Adding Linear layers to Thinc Model Example - Understanding Data Dimensions Through Model Architecture

Tags: python, nlp, neural-network, spacy, spacy-transformers

Trying to learn the inner workings of models trained with Spacy, and Thinc models are it. Looking at [this tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/explosion/thinc/blob/master/examples/02_transformers_tagger_bert.ipynb#scrollTo=EYYyAeLqRc6S) and I'm modifying the model to see what breaks and what works. Instead of tagging, I'm modifying it to fit a NER dataset I have with 16 classes. I want to add several layers after the TransformerTokenizer + Transformer layers already outlined in this tutorial, but I'm getting tons of dimension ValueErrors. Also, it's important to me that the TransformersTagger layer outputs the last hidden layer of the given transformer model, which I'm not confident this code is doing. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
ValueError: Attempt to change dimension 'nI' for model 'linear' from 512 to 16
```

And here is my full code adaptation to date. To be fair, I don't like that there's a softmax(num_ner_classes) prior to the Linear() layer, but I can't get anything else to work with with_array() after the Transformer layer:

```
@dataclass
class TokensPlus:
    batch_size: int
    tok2wp: List[Ints1d]
    input_ids: torch.Tensor
    token_type_ids: torch.Tensor
    attention_mask: torch.Tensor

    def __init__(self, inputs: List[List[str]], wordpieces: BatchEncoding):
        self.input_ids = wordpieces["input_ids"]
        self.attention_mask = wordpieces["attention_mask"]
        self.token_type_ids = wordpieces["token_type_ids"]
        self.batch_size = self.input_ids.shape[0]
        self.tok2wp = []
        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            print(i, inputs[i])
            spans = [wordpieces.word_to_tokens(i, j) for j in range(len(inputs[i]))]
            print(spans)
            self.tok2wp.append(self.get_wp_starts(spans))

    def get_wp_starts(self, spans: List[Optional[TokenSpan]]) -> Ints1d:
        """Calculate an alignment mapping each token index to its first wordpiece."""
        alignment = numpy.zeros((len(spans)), dtype="i")
        for i, span in enumerate(spans):
            if span is None:
                raise ValueError(
                    "Token did not align to any wordpieces. Was the tokenizer "
                    "run with is_split_into_words=True?"
                )
            else:
                alignment[i] = span.start
        return alignment

@thinc.registry.layers("transformers_tokenizer.v1")
def TransformersTokenizer(name: str) -> Model[List[List[str]], TokensPlus]:
    def forward(model, inputs: List[List[str]], is_train: bool):
        tokenizer = model.attrs["tokenizer"]
        wordpieces = tokenizer(
            inputs,
            is_split_into_words=True,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            return_token_type_ids=True,
            return_attention_mask=True,
            return_length=True,
            return_tensors="pt",
            padding="longest"
        )
        return TokensPlus(inputs, wordpieces), lambda d_tokens: []

    return Model("tokenizer", forward, attrs={"tokenizer": AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(name)})

def convert_transformer_inputs(model, tokens: TokensPlus, is_train):
    kwargs = {
        "input_ids": tokens.input_ids,
        "attention_mask": tokens.attention_mask,
        "token_type_ids": tokens.token_type_ids,
    }
    return ArgsKwargs(args=(), kwargs=kwargs), lambda dX: []

def convert_transformer_outputs(model: Model, inputs_outputs: Tuple[TokensPlus, Tuple[torch.Tensor]], is_train: bool) -> Tuple[List[Floats2d], Callable]:
    tplus, trf_outputs = inputs_outputs
    wp_vectors = torch2xp(trf_outputs[0])
    tokvecs = [wp_vectors[i, idx] for i, idx in enumerate(tplus.tok2wp)]

    def backprop(d_tokvecs: List[Floats2d]) -> ArgsKwargs:
        # Restore entries for BOS and EOS markers
        d_wp_vectors = model.ops.alloc3f(*trf_outputs[0].shape, dtype="f")
        for i, idx in enumerate(tplus.tok2wp):
            d_wp_vectors[i, idx] += d_tokvecs[i]
        return ArgsKwargs(
            args=(trf_outputs[0],),
            kwargs={"grad_tensors": xp2torch(d_wp_vectors)},
        )

    return tokvecs, backprop

@thinc.registry.layers("transformers_encoder.v1")
def Transformer(name: str = "bert-large-cased") -> Model[TokensPlus, List[Floats2d]]:
    return PyTorchWrapper(
        AutoModel.from_pretrained(name),
        convert_inputs=convert_transformer_inputs,
        convert_outputs=convert_transformer_outputs,
    )

@thinc.registry.layers("TransformersNer.v1")
def TransformersNer(name: str, num_ner_classes: int = 16) -> Model[List[List[str]], List[Floats2d]]:
    return chain(
        TransformersTokenizer(name),
        Transformer(name),
        with_array(Softmax(num_ner_classes)),
        Linear(512, 1024)
    )
```

How do I best determine how to pipe the output of the PyTorchWrapped TransformersTagger layer into a Linear() + more layers down the chain? I've been using this model visualization but even when I run model.initialize() on the first examples of my data, there are still a lot of (?, ?).

```
import pydot

def visualize_model(model):
    def get_label(layer):
        layer_name = layer.name
        nO = layer.get_dim("nO") if layer.has_dim("nO") else "?"
        nI = layer.get_dim("nI") if layer.has_dim("nI") else "?"
        return f"{layer.name}|({nO}, {nI})".replace(">", "&gt;")
    dot = pydot.Dot()
    dot.set("rankdir", "LR")
    dot.set_node_defaults(shape="record", fontname="arial", fontsize="10")
    dot.set_edge_defaults(arrowsize="0.7")
    nodes = {}
    for i, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
        label = get_label(layer)
        node = pydot.Node(layer.id, label=label)
        dot.add_node(node)
        nodes[layer.id] = node
        if i == 0:
            continue
        from_node = nodes[model.layers[i - 1].id]
        to_node = nodes[layer.id]
        if not dot.get_edge(from_node, to_node):
            dot.add_edge(pydot.Edge(from_node, to_node))
    print(dot)
```

Produces:

```
digraph G {
rankdir=LR;
node [fontname=arial, fontsize=10, shape=record];
edge [arrowsize="0.7"];
176 [label="tokenizer|(?, ?)"];
177 [label="pytorch|(?, ?)"];
176 -> 177;
179 [label="with_array(softmax)|(16, 1024)"];
177 -> 179;
180 [label="linear|(512, 1024)"];
179 -> 180;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OKAY, so here's how you traverse a Thinc model chain to inspect how data shapes change between layers. For each layer in `model.layers`, you can do the following and look at the data type and shape of the output of each layer. So what I ended up doing is modifying the `convert_transformer_output` and returned the `Ragged` representation of `tokvecs` instead of the list of variable length embeddings (because different sentences have more tokens than another).

```
    ...
    tokvecs = [wp_vectors[i, idx] for i, idx in enumerate(tplus.tok2wp)]
    tokvecs_ragged = list2ragged().predict(tokvecs).data
    ...
    return tokvecs_ragged, backprop
```

Ragged is more memory efficient than Padded and it feeds directly into a Linear layer, so I don't need `with_array()` at all anymore (whose purpose is also to return a numpy array). That way I get the shape I want and I can save my Softmax for the very end of my architecture (I have more layers I intend to add). Just took me a sec to look at the docs. This was the most revealing (see Chain Combinator [here](https://thinc.ai/docs/concept)).

```
    tok = model.layers[0]    # Tokenizer
    out, dX = tok(train_X[:5], is_train=False)
    print(out.input_ids.shape)
    trans = model.layers[1]  # Transformer
    out, dY = trans(out, is_train= False)
    print(out.shape)
    lin = model.layers[2] # Linear
    out, dZ = lin(out, is_train=False)
    print([el.shape for el in out])
```